# RxJava 2 Nested Network Requests

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2, flatmap

in the app I am currently working on I use retrofit to create an `Observable <ArrayList<Party>>`.

`Party` has a `hostId` field as well as a field of type `User` which is null at the point of creation by Retrofits GsonConverter. I now want to use `hostId` to make a second request getting the user from id and adding the `User` to the initial `Party`. I have been looking into flatmap but I haven't found an example in which the first observable's results are not only kept but also modified.

Currently, to get all parties without the `User` I am doing :

```
Observable<ArrayList<Party>> partiesObs = model.getParties();

partiesObs.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(this::handlePartyResponse, this::handleError);
```

How would I go about adding `User` to every `Party` without having to call `model.getUsers()` in the `onSuccess()` method of the inital call and then having to iterate through the two lists?

I understand that `flatmap()` returns a new Observable while `map` doesn't but I am unsure about how to use either in this scenario.

Thank you

Comment: Are you planning to perform a request to fetch `User` for each `Party` from the list, returned by `getParties()` request? If yes, you should consider changing the API of backend.

Comment: As far as backend solutions go, GraphQL is meant for such queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comment, you should try and get the backend API changed for something like this to avoid an inelegant and inefficient solution.

If this is not feasible, you could probably do something like this:

```
    .flatMapIterable(list -> list)
    .flatMap(party -> model.getUser(party.hostId),
            (party, user) -> new Party(user, party.hostId, party.dontCare))
```

Where:

1. `flatMapIterable` flattens the `Observable<ArrayList<Party>>` into an `Observable<Party>`
2. The overload of [`flatMap`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#flatMap-io.reactivex.functions.Function-io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction-) takes a `Function` for transforming emissions (`Party` objects) into an `ObservableSource` (of `User` objects) as the first parameter. The second parameter is a `BiFunction` for combining the `Party` and `User` objects which you can use to create a fully fledged `Party` object.

The last step is much easier if you have a `copy` or `clone` operation on the `Party` object that takes a previous instance and adds fields to it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This looks like exactly what I needed as for now I am simply mocking the Backend and don't have the option to change the API. I knoe that this will be sort of an inefficient workaround but that's all I need for the time being. One follow-up question:
Would a simple setter method for User not be sufficient or am I misunderstanding what you mean by copy operator?

Comment: @Wiintend0 you could use setters although generally it&#39;s a good idea to follow Effective Java item 15 and make classes immutable